# How to convey the meaning of "ordering a mess of papers and books"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How do English people convey the meaning of the action of tidying up *a great unordered amount of sheets of paper, books, and notes* in a single word or phrase?

Comment: My wife would use the term "bonfire".

Comment: 'arrange", straighten, organize etc.

Comment: I organize or tidy up my 'filing system'. Apparently random piles of books and papers on the chairs, sofa, floor, and windowsills **do** constitute a filing system.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger : I prefer to think of piles of stuff as 'chronological ordered by most recent use'.  If you have multiple piles, they're likely organized by some other concept, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think most people (I'm Canadian, not English, but I feel fairly confident in this proposition) would simply say **organize**:

> (v) arrange into a structured whole; order. [from Google dictionary]